# Callback on clicking on UIAlertView label(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am aware that callback can be managed if the user taps on the buttons of an UIAlertView. Is there a way to get a callback if the user taps on the title of the UIAlertView or on any label on the alert view?

Comment: Just my opinion, but I don't think so. If you wanted that, you'd need to extend the class of uialertview and add listeners to all the elements you need.

Comment: You cannot subclass it: *The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.* but there are replacements.

Comment: Create or Use Custom Alert View as its only option you got here.

Comment: Am creating that view. Shall update once done